# Progress bar to show only during long operations

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, thread-safety, waithandle

I am designing an application that fetches data from a sqlite database on the click of a button . I want to display a wait message or progress bar during the time of the fetch only if the process is long like say more than 3 secs . Otherwise it can just proceed with the program . How do i do this . i tried showing a progress dialog using the following code but it only waits for the specified sleep time and proceeds without showing anything .... plss help

```
protected void GetOrders() 
{
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    try
    {
        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(loginScreen.this,"PLEASE WAIT","LOADING CONTENTS ..",true);
        //Accesses database 
        allOrders=ProductionOrdersBL.GetOrder();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    finally
    {
        dialog.dismiss(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ... I had some operations after the call of the execute method . Thus while the doInBackground() method was executing in a non-UI thread , my UI thread simply continued executing the code that followed the execute method call ... The solution is to perform no task in the main UI thread following the execute method call :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all for showing progress bar you should use AsyncTask()([this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). and then in its `preExecute()` method say

```
try{
thread.sleep(3000);
dialog=ProgressDialog.show(loginScreen.this,"PLEASE WAIT","LOADING CONTENTS ..",true);

}catch(){
}
```

then in postExecute() use

```
if(dialog.isShowing()){
 dialog.dismiss
}
```

Comment: Hey i am still stuck .... the doInBackground() method in AsyncTask returns to the postExecute method even before it is completely done ... How do i stop this ?

Comment: thats something impossible.. that will never happen. may be there is some other problem, may be exceptions while fetching data from server. always postExecute() is called only after doInBackground() is complete..

Comment: Ok imagine this .... i show my dialog on preExecute() and in doInBackground() i call a thread.sleep(4000) and in postExecute() i call dialog.dismiss() . the postExecute() method is executed even before the sleep period is complete . Is this because i am using a thread or something ....

Comment: don't put sleep method in doInbackgeround(), do it preExecute() like i told. then in postExecute() use if(dialog.isShowing()){}

Comment: The idea is that my database access happens in the doinbackgrnd() method . As of now i am filling dummy data so i want to cause a delay in the doinbackgrnd() method just as what might happen during a database fetch . What i observe is that , this method is still running while the postExecute function gets called ... i even tried giving nested for loops to cause a delay but the postExecute is called even before the loops are complete ... how can this be possible ...

Comment: i have defined my asynctask this way  --> protected classname extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {With all functions as i mentioned above} and i call my task this way : new classname().execute();